# Retrieving the length of a list in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do a mongo query where I get the length of an array in each document, without retrieving the full contents of the list.  Ideally, this would be a projection option along these lines:

```
db.log.find({},{entries:{$length: 1}})
```

but this isn't supported.  Maybe this is possible in an elegant way with the new aggregation framework?  What I've come up with is this:

```
db.log.find({},{"entries.length": 1})
```

Which returns results like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d2fb07e64cfa55431de693"), "entries" : [   {    },     {    },     {    },     {    },     {    },     {    },     {    },     {  },   {    },     {    },     {    },     {    },     {    },     {  },   {    },     {    },     {    },     {    } ] }
```

This is ugly but basically serves my needs since I can count the length of this list without the network weight of getting the full contents.  But I have no idea why this works.  What is this query actually doing?

Comment: I believe it's returning the `length` field of each element of the array - since this presumably isn't set for any of them, you get an empty object for each element of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, I could think in two approachs:

1) Using aggregation framework:

```
db.log.aggregate([ { $unwind : "$entries" }, { $group : { _id : "$_id", entries : {$sum:1}  } }  ]);
```

2) Or you can add a field to the document that holds the entries count. So, each time that you push a new value to entries array, you must increment the counter. The update will be like this:

```
db.log.update({ _id : 123 }, { $push : { entries : 'value' }, $inc : { entriesCount : 1 } })
```

Clearly, you have a trade-off here: the aggregation framework is too expensive for this simple operation. But adding a field to document, every update should increment the counter.

IMHO, the counter looks more reasonable, though it looks a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the mongodb documentation:](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

You can use as well $size:

```
db.log.aggregate([{$project:{'_id':1, 'count':{$size: "$entriesCount"}}}]);
```