# MongoDB MongoEngine ListField get count() \ len()

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

here is my document

```
class Store(Document):
    store_id = IntField(required=True)
    items = ListField(ReferenceField(Item, required=True))
    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            {
                'fields': ['campaign_id'],
                'unique': True
            },
            {
               'fields': ['items']
            }
        ]
    }
```

I can not find how to get ListFIeld len\count with retrieving whole list
i need something like

```
documents.Store.objects.get(store_id=27).items.count()
```

I've found vay how to do that via mongo console

```
db.store.find({"store_id" : 27})[0].items.length;
```

but i need via Mongoengine.

Does len(documents.Store.objects.get(store_id=27).items) will  retrieve all documents then count  them via Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the length of a list in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958490/retrieving-the-length-of-a-list-in-mongodb)

Comment: Your example in the console also retrieves the items list and gets the length - same as the mongoengine example.  The only way to do this is either add a counter field (pre compute the aggregation) or use the aggregation framework to project and compute the size of the list

Comment: so, i've added new field

    items_count = IntField(default=0)

and how on add_to_set inc this counter?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can call `len()` function on `Store.objects.get(store_id = 27).items` because `items` is a `BaseList` type 
like this `len(Store.objects.get(store_id = 27).items` 
but I can't find any mongoengine syntax for this 
and it's usual because `BaseList` is not a mongoengine type :D